# Unable to Display Page Title Using wp_title() Function in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Can you please let me know how I can use the wp_title() function to grab each page titles in WordPress. I used the following code to get the title in different page based on titles but it dost' work!

Here is the code I am using

```
<title>
       <?php 
             if (is_front_page()) {
                          bloginfo('name'); }
             elseif (is_page()) {
                          wp_title(); echo ' - '; bloginfo('name'); }
       ?>
</title>
```

Comment: what is issue? is it goes into else if condition every time?

Comment: what do you mean by doesnt work ? do we have to guess ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?>
```

Here is the function reference link : http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_title

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you may use

```
<title>
  <?php
    if ( is_home() ) {
      bloginfo('name');
    } else {
      wp_title('',true,'');
      echo " | ";
      bloginfo('name');
    }
  ?>
</title>
```