# How to Display Page Title Using wp_title() in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

i can try this :

```
<?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?>
```

but display web page URL in page title.

Comment: Elaborate your question please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try this..

```
 <title><?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?></title>
```

For more info: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title

Answer (score 1):

this code will return page title by slug

```
<?php
                    global $wp_query;
                    $post_id = $wp_query->post->ID;
                    $post = get_post($post_id);
                    $slug = $post->post_title;
                    echo $slug;
                ?>
```

also you can refer 
[Unable to Display Page Title Using wp_title() Function in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19675725/unable-to-display-page-title-using-wp-title-function-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

You might have wanted to get title of a current post.

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
<?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title
If you want just the url you can use the `the_permalink()` function

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `the_title()`, this function displays only the page title.

Or use the `wp_title( '|', true, 'right' )`, this function displays like `testpage | sitename`